# Calculating possible combinations in a 2D or 3D array

Tags: combinatorics

I come from a programming background so the terminology that I use might not adhere to proper mathematical terminology.

I have read a few questions similar to this but found them to only account for the first case that I am going to describe.

I wanted to calculate the possible combinations of binary values or RGB values in a 2D or arguably 3D array, representing an image.

In the first case, values in the array are binary. The values can be 0 or 1.

If there is a 4x4 grid, with 16 total cells, there are 2^16 possible combinations.

In the case of RGB however, there is another dimension adding complexity to the calculation and I wanted to make sure that my logic is correct.

It goes as follows:

- There is a 4x4 pixel grid.
- There are 16 cells in this grid.
- Each position can contain an RGB value, where Red, Green, and Blue all hold a value of 0-255 (this would technically make the structure a 3D array).
- Per cell, the possible values are 255^3 = 16,581,375
- Taking the product of the last calculation as the base, and the number of positions as the exponent, there are 16,581,375^16 possible combinations

Is this logic correct?

Comment: [0-255] would be 256 possible values actually. Otherwise your calculation looks fine to me.

Comment: @Leaderboard Ah yes, I missed that. Thank you!